# Mapping data transfer object to domain Cyclic dependencies

Tags: java

I am trying to find a way to create these mappers without having problems with cyclic dependencies. I want to make it with a clean solution and I do not want to make the methods static for testing reasons. Any good idea?

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customers")
public class CustomerT {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "custmerId")
  private Long customerId;

  @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "Surname", nullable = false)
  private String surname;

  @Column(name = "Age")
  private int age;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orders",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<OrderT> orderTSet;
  public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
  }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class OrderT {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long orderId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "custmerId", referencedColumnName = "custmerId")
  private CustomerT customerT;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "OrdersProducts",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderId"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "productId"))
  private List<ProductT> productTList;
```

```java
public class CustomerMapper {

  @Inject
  OrderMapper orderMapper;

  public CustomerD mapEntityToDomain(final CustomerT customerT) {
    final CustomerD customerD = new CustomerD();
    customerD.setCustomerId(customerT.getCustomerId());
    customerD.setName(customerT.getName());
    customerD.setAge(customerT.getAge());
    customerD.setSurname(customerT.getSurname());
    customerD.setOrderDSet(orderMapper.mapSetEntityToDomain(customerT.getOrderTSet()));
    return customerD;
  }
```

```java
public class OrderMapper {

  @Inject
  ProductMapper productMapper;

  @Inject
  CustomerMapper customerMapper;

  public OrderD mapEntityToDomain(final OrderT orderT) {
    final OrderD orderD = new OrderD();
    orderD.setId(orderT.getOrderId());
    orderD.setCustomerD(customerMapper.mapEntityToDomain(orderT.getCustomerT()));
    orderD.setProductDList(productMapper.mapListEntityToDomain(orderT.getProductTList()));
    return orderD;
  }
```

"org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001443: Pseudo scoped bean has circular dependencies."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your domain objects, it looks like you have the CustomerD pointing to his/her OrdersD and the OrdersD pointing to the CustomerD. As far as I can understand, the strong relationship is between the CoustomerD -> OrdersD and the reference from the OrderD to the CustomerD looks like just something convenient for you.

In this case, the OrderD mapper should not create a new CustomerD by itself. Doing this will duplicate entities (each order will generate a new instance of the CustomerD), and that is not what you want.

Just create a new method for OrderMapper that just maps the Order:

```
public class OrderMapper {

  @Inject
  ProductMapper productMapper;

  @Inject
  CustomerMapper customerMapper;

  public OrderD mapEntityToDomainJustEntity(final OrderT orderT) {
    final OrderD orderD = new OrderD();
    orderD.setId(orderT.getOrderId());
    return orderD;
  }

  public OrderD mapEntityToDomain(final OrderT orderT) {
    final OrderD orderD = mapEntityToDomainJustEntity(orderT);         
    orderD.setCustomerD(customerMapper.mapEntityToDomain(orderT.getCustomerT()));
    return orderD;
  }
```

And call this new method from your CustomerMapper. Then set the custormer of each OrderD to 'this'

```
public class CustomerMapper {

  @Inject
  OrderMapper orderMapper;

  public CustomerD mapEntityToDomain(final CustomerT customerT) {
    final CustomerD customerD = new CustomerD();
    customerD.setCustomerId(customerT.getCustomerId());
    customerD.setName(customerT.getName());
    customerD.setAge(customerT.getAge());
    customerD.setSurname(customerT.getSurname());

customerD.setOrderDSet(orderMapper.mapSetEntityToDomainJustEntity(customerT.getOrderTSet()));

    // foreach OrderD -> orderD.setCustomerD(this);
    return customerD;
  }
```